# Why do professional-made websites have odd #id and .class names?

Tags: css

I noticed that facebook and gmail have really odd #id and .class names.

Do they obfuscate them on purpose? or does their IDE does it? 
It doesn't seem logical to have such unreadable names for development

for example - this is gmail's refresh button. It would be reasonable to have id/class as "refresh"

```
<div class="G-Ni J-J5-Ji" style="">
<div class="T-I J-J5-Ji nu T-I-ax7 L3" act="20" role="button" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;" data-tooltip="Refresh" aria-label="Refresh">
<div class="asa">
<span class="J-J5-Ji ask">&nbsp;</span><div class="asf T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji"></div></div></div></div>
```

and facebook's post button for status update

```
<button class="_42ft _42fu _11b selected _42g-" type="submit">Post</button>
```

on performance - does have shorter name really impact load times? it would seem it is (for a large page such as facebook or gmail) a couple of 100kb more, which with today broadband line is negligible for the time needed

on exception - twitter and pinterest have readable names

Comment: Note: it does not have anything to do with "professionalism".

Comment: Most of their contents are dynamic, so the odd ones you see are probably generated accordingly by their framework and not really manual entries.

The static portions have proper names, for instance facebook's left tool bar has the id `leftCol`.

Comment: I'm sure I read a very similar question last week

Comment: I believe they are often just abbreviations, e.g. `xjsi` on Google's search screen could mean `x JavaScript init` (contains the loader of additional JavaScript) and `xjsd` could mean `x JavaScript destination` (element where we save additional scripts), where `x` is just a sign that the element is active. However, this are just assumptions. However, other than that, generated names can follow some weird rules.

Comment: Interesting question. They also (at least Gmail) use tons of nested divs.

Comment: Considering the amount of data sent out by Facebook and Google, then yes, saving a few bytes here and there make a LOT of difference. This translates into less energy consumption and bandwidth used, which directly translates into money saved.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Update: CSS Modules

This practice is now known as "CSS Modules" and is becoming more widely adopted with the popularity of Webpack. The concept is to transform (hash) CSS selectors into unique class names, to ensure that there are no collisions of styles between modules.

The [css-loader module](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#css-modules) for Webpack has a `modules` option which enables this feature. It is commonly used with React, where you assign class names in your markup via a JS object made available by importing the CSS file, e.g.

```
import styles from './style.css
```

If that CSS file has a selector, e.g. `.sidebar`, it is applied in the markup via

```
className={styles.sidebar} // JSX
```

Webpack will hash the class name and matcing selector to ensure uniqueness.

#### Original answer ↓

This would be a product of minification and compression. It would no doubt be written with human readable id and class names, but like Zeta has commented, these are then substituted with abbreviations to save bytes. Such things don't matter to the average website, but when you're getting billions of pageviews an minute, it all counts.

Take a look at the difference between the [development](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) and [production](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) versions of jQuery. This is an example of the result of minification and compression.

Comment: seems logical, but I don't buy it. Looking at alexa top sites, youtube has very readable id and class names and they aren't short. yahoo seems to have a combination of this.. with something like this `<div class="searchwrapper tabpanel selected" id="p_13838465-searchwrapper" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="yui_3_4_0_1_1360241032142_164">`. wikipedia also has readable names. Also, twitter and pinterest (which are very popular) have readable names, amazon.com as well. So all these popular websites don't care for these bytes, but facebook does? I doubt it

Comment: Could it be to prevent data scraping? If the id/class names are gibberish and dynamic, it'd be very hard to do scrape data. One would have to rely on element ordering/nesting.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because they compile their code, i mean like google they write code in java and rest all is handled with [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) same thing about facebook they write using C and then do the same thing.

Comment: Your first statement is correct about the code being compiled. However, Facebook's front-end code is *not* compiled from C :)

Comment: Facebook used to transpile their PHP code (which is used for the front end development) into C++ which was then compiled into a binary and run as an executable. This was mainly done for performance reasons but now instead the PHP code is compiled into an intermediate bytecode which is then run by the HipHop Virtual Machine which is a just-in-time compiler.