# How does Facebook and google randomize the html selector id and class names?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, facebook

For example,

```
<div class="_4-u2 _1qby focus_target _4-u8" id="rc.u_0_x"></div>
```

I'm sure the dev version would comprise human readable & contextual selector names.

I can understand the why part. For why, refer [Why do professional-made websites have odd #id and .class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746261/why-do-professional-made-websites-have-odd-id-and-class-names)

I'm trying to figure out the how part. Is there a npm package or js library that helps in randomizing the names to a prod version.

Answer (score 0):

They're not random, but they are not fixed either. They're usually used for component identification or a result of compilation/optimization, and it's implementation-specific.

For instance, if I remember correctly, React has `data-reactid` attribute with a random number value on elements for component identification. Ractive.js has `data-ractive` attribute with a 32-character hash value on elements for CSS scoping purposes. The BEM CSS naming convention has a `.block__element--modifier` class name structure which can easily be condensed into a few characters.