# How to make CSS class names unreadable with Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I found a Webpack module https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#css-modules
which is able to rename class names and makes class names unreadable.

I found a SO answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14751344/5369031 but I am very curious how we can achieve the same thing in Angular CLI during `ng build --prod` ?

Unreadable means:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if you can use a flag for it or not. I did not find anything from the docs: https://angular.io/cli/build. You could try the flag `--optimization=true`, but I don't know if that works. I have not read this github issue (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10705) yet, but maybe it is of help.

Answer (score 1):

What https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#css-modules does is enabling [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

I was able to implement [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) in an Angular 8 application (it's possible to do it in Angular 7 or higher too) customizing the build thanks to [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) and then using [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) and [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules).

[postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) hash all the styles, then [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules) replaces the class names on the html files by the hashed class names.

I documented my solution here:

- Live Demo: https://angular-css-modules.herokuapp.com/
- Github Repo: https://github.com/gquinteros93/angular-css-modules
- Article with the step by step: https://indepth.dev/angular-css-modules/

I hope it will be useful for you.